# i'm unable to understand why this block of code is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to implement the following function.
what it does is:

1. takes a coordinate.
2. assigns weights to surrounding cells.
3. stores these weights and cell direction in a map.
4. loops through the map. starting with the lowest weight.
5. calls move again with the neighbour cell coordinate.

Code snippet:

```
120 void move(const int x, const int y)
121 {
122         map<int, int> nextDir;
123         map<int, int>::iterator it;
124         if((x == maxX - 1) && (y == maxY - 1))
125         {
126                 int groundCopy[maxX][maxY];
127                 memcpy(((void *)&groundCopy), ((void *)&ground), sizeof(groundCopy));
128                 traceBack(x, y);
129                 memcpy(((void *)&ground), ((void *)&groundCopy), sizeof(ground));
130                 printPPM();
131         }
132         for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
133         {
134                 if(!isValid(x + dirX[i], y + dirY[i]))
135                         continue;
136                 int temp = weight[x][y][0] + ground[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]] + disWeight(x, y, x + dirX[i], y + dirY[i]);
137                 if(!(weight[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]][0] == numeric_limits<int>::max()))
138                         temp += weight[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]][0];
139                 if(temp < weight[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]][0])
140                 {
141                         weight[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]][0] = temp;
142                         weight[x + dirX[i]][y + dirY[i]][1] = 7 - i;
143                         nextDir[temp] = i;
144                 }
145                 else
146                         continue;
147         }
148         for(it = nextDir.begin(); it != nextDir.end(); ++it)
149                 move(x + dirX[it->second], y + dirY[it->second]);
150 }
```

backtrace info:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401760 in move (x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff5ab18c>, y=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff5ab188>) at codes/terrainExample.cpp:121
121 {
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000401760 in move (x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff5ab18c>, y=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff5ab188>) at codes/terrainExample.cpp:121
#1  0x0000000000401bfa in move (x=0, y=1) at codes/terrainExample.cpp:149
#2  0x0000000000401bfa in move (x=0, y=0) at codes/terrainExample.cpp:149
#3  0x0000000000401dbb in solve () at codes/terrainExample.cpp:167
#4  0x0000000000401f1c in main () at codes/terrainExample.cpp:186
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Following is the link to the code and the valgrind log if needed:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m8zfxubq6lcl8o/terrainExample.cpp?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wq7ob1uevwutsov/logfile.out?dl=0

In this code I'm using vector instead of map.

Comment: Check your index variables when stepping through your code with the debugger, and ensure you access your arrays in bounds.

Comment: line 134 i'm doing that.
bool isValid(const int x, const int y) {if((x<0) || (y<0) || (x>=maxX) || (y>=maxY)) return false; return true;}
in debug also i checked.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting piece of code, I had really fun looking at it. So let's dissect it.

Firstly, valgrind complains, that:

`==15718== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0xfff000420 --> 0xffed6b8d8`

This tells me there's is a stack smashing somewhere. After browsing through the code, indeed there are HUGE local variables stored on the stack, so, either:

1. try to reduce the size of the image (for example setting 
   `const int maxX = 320; const int maxY = 640;` fixes the stack problem)
2. But if you really need large image sizes, simply do dynamic memory management.

However, the application still crashes somewhere ... and I find that calling `nextMove` over and over in a recursion ... well, again disturbs the stack. So, to make things better, do something like this:

1. change `nextMove` from `void nextMove(const int x, const int y)` to `void nextMove(int x, int y)`. I just removed the constness of the parameters, you'll see in a minute why.
2. add a label, just at the beginning of the function:

   `void nextMove(int x, int y)
    {
        again:`

   and last but not least:
3. Instead of calling recursively the function at the end `nextMove(nx, ny);`, do something like: `x = nx; y = ny; goto again;`

Some people will simply hate me for using `goto` so I'll ask them to provide an answer which hasn't got any `goto`s  in them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @fritzone, it worked. i changed all the large arrays to get dynamically allocated. did not use goto as it would have changed the x and y value of the preset nextMove call.